# How invoke a Spring Integration application from your CXF endpoint

Tags: spring, cxf, spring-integration

i'm using Apache CXF web services and Spring Integration and i don't now how to invoke a Spring Integration application from your CXF endpoint.

I have experience working on Apache Camel and is very easy to resolve this problem...but in Spring Integration i don't have any idea....

My lines code are:

1. In webservices-definition-beans.xml:

   ```
   <!-- Load CXF modules from cxf.jar -->
   <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
   <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml"/>
   <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>

   <!--Exposing the HelloWorld service as a SOAP service -->
   <bean id="jaxbBean"
         class="org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding"
         scope="prototype"/>

   <bean id="jaxws-and-aegis-service-factory"
         class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean"
         scope="prototype">
       <property name="dataBinding" ref="jaxbBean"/>
       <property name="serviceConfigurations">
       <list>
           <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceConfiguration"/>
           <bean class="org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.AegisServiceConfiguration"/>
           <bean class="org.apache.cxf.service.factory.DefaultServiceConfiguration"/>
       </list>
   </property>
   </bean>

   <jaxws:endpoint id="helloWorld"
               serviceName="HelloWorldService"
               implementorClass="com.datys.cxf.HelloWorldService"
               address="/HelloWorld">
       <jaxws:serviceFactory>
           <ref bean="jaxws-and-aegis-service-factory"/>
       </jaxws:serviceFactory>
   </jaxws:endpoint>
   ```
2. In service-definition-beans.xml:

   ```
   <gateway id="HelloWorldService" 
            default-request-channel="requestStrings"
            default-reply-channel="replyStrings"             
            service-interface="com.datys.cxf.HelloWorldService">
       <method name="sayHello"/>
   </gateway>

   <channel id="requestStrings"/>
   <channel id="replyStrings"/> 

   <!--<channel id="filesOut"/>-->
   <service-activator input-channel="requestStrings"
                      output-channel="filesOut"
                      ref="handler" method="handleString"/>

   <file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesOut" 
                                  directory="file:D:/OUTPUT"/>

   <beans:bean id="handler" class="org.springframework.integration.samples.filecopy.Handler"/>
   ```

But when i deploy and call web services with client-webservices return this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Could not instantiate service     class com.datys.cxf.HelloWorldService because it is an interface.
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:171)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:94)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:240)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:210)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:103)
at $Proxy29.sayHello(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the simplest option is to configure a <gateway>. That allows you to provide any interface that you can inject into your endpoint and invoke it to initiate a message flow. Under the covers, the interface is implemented in the same way as other "ProxyFactoryBean" implementations in Spring (e.g. remoting via RMI, HttpInvoker, etc).

Here's a relevant section from the reference manual:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/2.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#gateway-proxy

Comment: I solved this problem inspired by your answer. I created normal cxf web services and, in the implementation, i call gateway beans to route request message in my spring integration flow...It is not a pretty solution but It works ok...!